# Higher Algebra. What topic is this and where I can read about it?

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I want to find some information about how to solve this problem but I don't even know what topic is this. Maybe it's related to symmetric functions. I've tried searching in books but nothing similar found. I will be glad for any kind of help. Thanks.

PROBLEM:

Let $$f_m = \frac{1}{m} \{((x-y)(z-t))^m + ((x-z)(y-t))^m + ((x-t)(y-z))^m \} $$

Prove that $ f_5^2 = f_3 f_7 $

[Question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4YD2.png)

Comment: Looks like just straight tedious elementary algebra. I’m sure Mathematica would confirm that the identity is true, but I don’t know if this would help you prove it “by hand”.

Comment: @bubba There are ways to exploit symmetry but it is painful looking.

Comment: I don't think this is true.  If $x=y=1,z=0,t=-1$, then I get $$f_5=\frac{(0\cdot1)^5+(1\cdot2)^5+(2\cdot1)^5}5=\frac{64}5$$  There's no way we'll get $5$ in the denominator from $f_3f_7$.  Have I made an error?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. But it's not supposed to be proven by hand. There are other more complicated identities that also should be done.

Comment: I would be happy just to know what topic is this. ) Thank you all.